# AWS device farm Appium Node.js - package.json not being found in bundled .zip file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I am getting the following error after the .tgz command runs. Has anyone seen this?

```py
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/scratchXEFHVJ.scratch/test-packageptX7bd/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/scratchXEFHVJ.scratch/test-packageptX7bd/package.json
```

This will later cause the wdio to not be found, as the node_modules never install I believe.

Running Appium v1.17.0
webdriverio

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: hey tim! we will figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to missing files

Try

```
npm init -y // intializing for the package JSON
```

Add Webdriver CLI tool

```
npm install --save webdriverio @wdio/cli
```

Update the config file

```
npx wdio config 
// after upadting
npx wdio ./wdio.conf.js
```

`npm install`

then create the bundle

```
npm install -g npm-bundle
```

Then create a zip

```
zip -r MyTest.zip *.tgz
```

then start testing part on AWS